# how to align input tags in html form?

Tags: html, css

I am making a Guestbook page right now and am having trouble aligning the input fields so it looks nice. Right now it looks very ugly and not organized. I just want everything (the inputs) to line up nicely. Thank you!

html:

```
<form>
Name <input type="text" name="guest" id="guest" input size="45"  maxlength="40" required/> <br />

E-mail address <input type="text" name="email" id="email" input size="60" maxlength="60" required/> <br />

City <input type="text" name="city" id="city" input size="35" maxlength="30" required/> <br />

 <select id="province" name="province" size="15" required>
        <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
        <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
        <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
        <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and  Labrador</option>
        <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
        <option value="Ontario" selected="selected">Ontario</option>
        <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
        <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
        <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
        <option value="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
        <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
        <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
</select> <br />

Web Page URL <input type="text" name="web_url" id="web_url" input size="60" maxlength="60" /> <br />

Web Page Title <input type="text" name="web_title" id="web_title" input size="25"  /> <br />

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comments" id="comments" >
Enter comments here...</textarea>

</form>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 max-width: 1000px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Error: Attribute input not allowed on element input at this point

Comment: also am recieving the above error for some reason i don't understand..

Comment: You have "input" written within your input tag. Remove it to get rid of the error

Comment: @13design if you have found any of the answers useful make sure to give them a vote and select one that answered your question with the tick. This will allow other to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap labels with `<label>` tag:

```
<label>Name </label><input type="text" name="guest" id="guest" input size="45"  maxlength="40" required/> <br />
```

Then add css:

```
label{width: 200px; float: left;}
```

[Full code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/rqwznpty/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**For horizontal align:**

Put all your inputs in a `<div>` tag and add this css to it:

```
div {
    float: left;
}
```

**For vertical align:**

Put all your inputs as a `<div>` and make each input a list:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Use this CSS:

```
div li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret is DIVs.

Use an outer div to surround each grouping, and inner divs for each inline group (left = title, right = input field).

Note that the inner divs are floated left -- this places them side by side. But it also removes them from the HTML "flow" and the `.outer` divs will have zero height. So, we add `overflow:______` (auto or hidden) to counter this. *Try removing the `overflow:hidden` and watch everything go to pieces.*

<kbd>[**jsFiddle for experimenting**](https://jsfiddle.net/aga6oLLb/1/)</kbd>

```css
body {
 max-width: 1000px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.outer{overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:5px;}
.in_left {float:left;width:100px;padding-right:10px;text-align:right;}
.in_right{float:left;width:250px;}
.in_right input{width:250px;}

.outer:last-of-type{margin-bottom:25px;}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="in_left">Name</div>
    <div class="in_right"><input type="text" name="guest" id="guest" size="45"  maxlength="40" required/></div>
  </div><!-- .outer -->

  <div class="outer">
    <div class="in_left">E-mail address </div>
    <div class="in_right"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="60" maxlength="60" required/> </div>
  </div><!-- .outer -->

  <div class="outer">
    <div class="in_left">City</div>
    <div class="in_right"><input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="35" maxlength="30" required/></div>
  </div><!-- .outer -->

 <select id="province" name="province" size="15" required>
        <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
        <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
        <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
        <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and  Labrador</option>
        <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
        <option value="Ontario" selected="selected">Ontario</option>
        <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
        <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
        <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
        <option value="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
        <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
        <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
</select> <br />

Web Page URL <input type="text" name="web_url" id="web_url" size="60" maxlength="60" /> <br />

Web Page Title <input type="text" name="web_title" id="web_title" size="25"  /> <br />

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comments" id="comments" >
Enter comments here...</textarea>

</form>
```

Comment: Error: Attribute input not allowed on element input at this point. I am getting this error on all my input tags now for some reason as well...?

Comment: ah, I missed that. Error do speak true. There is no need for an `input` attribute on the `<input>` tag.  This is wrong: `<input type="text" input width="50" />`, this is correct: `<input type="text" width="50" />`